# Check my proof of the product rule of limits for functions.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I want to prove: $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)g(x)=\left(\lim_{x \to c}f(x)\right)\left(\lim_{x \to c}g(x)\right)$$ where $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L_1 $ which means(1): $$\forall\epsilon_1>0, \exists \delta_1>0:|x-c|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-L_1|<\epsilon_1 $$  and $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=L_2$ which means(2): $$\forall\epsilon_2>0, \exists \delta_2>0:|x-c|<\delta_2\implies|g(x)-L_2|<\epsilon_2 $$
So I want to show that:  $$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0:|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)g(x)-L_1L_2|<\epsilon $$

First, let $$\delta= \min(\delta_1,\delta_2), \space \epsilon_1 =\dfrac{\epsilon}{2k} \space \text{and} \space \epsilon_2=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2n}$$ where $$k>|g(x)|, \space n>|L_1|$$

Substituting $\epsilon_1$ into (1), $$\forall\epsilon_1>0, \exists \delta_1>0:|x-c|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-L_1|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2k} $$ and $|f(x)-L_1|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2k}$  implies(3): $$|g(x)|\cdot |f(x)-L_1|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and substituting $\epsilon_2$ into (2), we get: $$\forall\epsilon_2>0, \exists \delta_2>0:|x-c|<\delta_2\implies|g(x)-L_2|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2n} $$ and that $|g(x)-L_2|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2n}$ implies(4): $$|L_1| \cdot |g(x)-L_2|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Adding (3) and (4), we get: $$|g(x)|\cdot |f(x)-L_1|+|L_1| \cdot |g(x)-L_2|=|g(x)\left(f(x)-L_1\right)|+|L_1\left(g(x)-L_2\right)|<\epsilon$$ Using the fact that: $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$, $$|g(x)\left(f(x)-L_1\right)+L_1\left(g(x)-L_2\right)|\le |g(x)\left(f(x)-L_1\right)|+|L_1\left(g(x)-L_2\right)| < \epsilon$$ Notice that: $$|g(x)\left(f(x)-L_1\right)+L_1\left(g(x)-L_2\right)|=|g(x)f(x)-g(x)L_1+L_1g(x)-L_1L_2|$$ which equals to: $$|f(x)g(x)-L_1L_2|$$ and is less than $\epsilon$. And we have proved what we wanted.

Edit: Fixed the proof;mistake was not accounting the scenario when $|L_1|=0$

Comment: Your proof is almost correct. Just replace the $|L_1|$ in denominator with $|L_1|+1$ to handle the case when $L_1=0$

Comment: I completely forgot about scenario! I'll fix that one with the same approach that I used for $\epsilon_1$ So $\frac{\epsilon}{2n}$ where $n>|L_1|$. That should fix it.

Comment: Yes that's the idea. But notice that this is a minor mistake (and is not related to the general idea behind the proof) and I suppose if this comes in exam there should not be any heavy penalty for such a mistake.